# Spring DAO performance

Tags: java, performance, spring, jdbc

What is Spring DAO JdbcTemplate performance compared with plain old JDBC? 
In other words how much overhead of using of Spring JdbcTemplate?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Should be minimal if any. Spring DAO templates promotes good programming pratices and hence should be used on those strenghts. Given you will be using database across multiple tiers etc, performance issue will be more I/O related as well as issues with individual queries etc.
HTH

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Can you give a link to performance comparision with concrete queries and time measurement?